# Problem importing wrl file in a urdf to work with gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We try to import a wrl file in our urdf text..... gazebo spawn the robot, but there is nothing on the GUI. Does anybody know the most probable reason? Thanks in advance for your interest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42484/problem-importing-wrl-file-in-a-urdf-to-work-with-gazebo/) by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on 2012-08-28**:
Thanks for the help. We converted the .wrl format to .stl and to .dae too. We changed the "mesh" instruction in the .urdf file and the object was successfully spawned in gazebo, though, for both case, we cannot see anything again on the program's GUI. Thanks again for your help...

**Comment by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on 2012-08-29**:
If it can be an help on the konsole this lines appear:   Warning [parser.cc:332] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:271]parse as sdf version 1.0 failed, trying to parse as old deprecated format
Warning [parser.cc:277]parse as old deprecated world file failed, trying old model format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo currently supports .STL and .DAE mesh formats (see for example, the [COLLADA mesh loader](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/72909f41da03/src/common/ColladaLoader.hh) and [STL mesh loader](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/72909f41da03/src/common/STLLoader.hh) in source tree.  If you have recommendations for additional mesh format support, please file a [feature request ticket / patch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new).

Alternatively, you can use mesh utilities such as [ivcon](http://ros.org/wiki/ivcon) to convert your WRL meshes to STL/DAE first.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1